# Java EE: Does EntityManager get method changing state in DB

Tags: java, entitymanager

I want to know if I can perform `em.remove` for each element in that local list? Does this code changes state in DB?

```
TypedQuery<Product> query = em.createNamedQuery("Product.findByCode", Product.class);
query.setParameter("code", code);
List<Product> productList= query.getResultList();
   for (int i = 1; i < productList.size(); i++) {
      em.remove(productList.get(i));
   }
```

Comment: Is the question you linked really similar to yours? There the OP asks to get _all_ entities via the entity manager while you want to remove products. Besides that, did you try it? What would you expect `remove(entity)` to do if not cause the entity manager to remove the entity from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it changes the DB, since that is his job.

> The EntityManager API is used to create and remove persistent entity instances, to find entities by their primary key, and to query over entities.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html